# Skrollr FIXED-based menu navigation with animateTo?

Tags: javascript, css, skrollr

I built a very simple website with skrollr using fixed-position based, full-screen panels that I scroll by transform:translating and I want to add a nav bar. Am I right that I cannot use skrollr-menu for this type of setup?

Is it possible to use animateTo on a click event to navigate a certain panel?
For example, to get to page 2, can I just make a button that animates to 100p?

```
<div id="page1" data-0="transform:translate(0,0%);" data-100p="transform:translate(0,-100%);">

<div id="page2" data-0="transform:translate(0,100%);" data-100p="transform:translate(0,0%);">
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. With the latest skrollr-menu you can use percentages as well

```
<a href="#page2" data-menu-top="100p">page 2</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, great to have an answer form the developer themselves. I tried this before, but had forceHeight=false pasted in from the example provided....works now. I feel silly. Thanks for providing such a fantastic piece of code to allow non-savvy people like me develop rich web experiences with minimal effort.